# How to update a MongoDB from Java with the current DB time?

Tags: java, mongodb, time

I want to update a mongo DB from my Java application with the current **DB** time (**not** the JVM's time).

If I had a shell, I would execute the following command:

```
db.colletion.update({_id : 'doc'}, {$set : { last_update : ISODate()}}, true, false);
```

I'm not sure how to translate it to java:

```java
Object lastUpdate = ???;
DBObject q = new BasicDBObject("_id", "doc");
DBObject o = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("last_update", lastUpdate));
collection.update(q, o, true, false);
```

I'm trying to figure out what should be `lastUpdate` object.

A new `Date` instance is not an option, because it will represent the JVM's time and not the DB's time.
I thought about using `eval` to get the time from the `DB`, but that will cost an extra query for each update.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the DB time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use `eval`. From the [`eval` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval):

> If you want to use the server’s interpreter, you must run `eval`. Otherwise, the mongo shell’s JavaScript interpreter evaluates functions entered directly into the shell.

even the command that you posted will **use the client's time**, not the server time, because the `ISODate` constructor will be evaluated on the client / shell.

Answer (score 2):

The next release of MongoDB (2.6) supports the $currentDate update operator.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#write-operation-improvements for details.